# How do I communicate between two projects in one solution?

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a "Google Chrome Extension" project in C#.(It's name is WordCounter) I need send a data a Console App, than send another data to WordCounter. Yes I know I have to add as Console App's referance to WordCounter but I tried it and I got nothing.

[image: Add as referance]

Then, I create a class in WordCounter project I added `using Console;`and it didn't work. How can i communicate between my projects?

Comment: Are you trying to reference them both from each other? Because that won't work.

Comment: Memory mapped file or sockets on localhost

Comment: Try using delegates.

Comment: I tried but when i try add WordCounter's referance to Console, i am getting "A referance to "WordCounter" could not be added" error. @TheAnathema